# Importing when using Vue javascript module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I'm using the `vue.esm.browser.js` module for Vue, which works without problems:

```
import Vue from 'vue.esm.browser.js';
```

I can't however find a way to import the `reactive` and `isReactive` functions. I've tried

```
import { reactive, isReactive } from 'vue.esm.browser.js';
```

but it doesn't work. I'd appreciate any help to get this working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned Vue version or where this file is coming from, but note the syntax:

Vue 2 (esm.browser), has a dot:

```
vue.esm.browser.js
```

Vue 3 (esm-browser), has a dash:

```
vue.esm-browser.js
```

I am guessing you are using Vue 2, which also does not support those exports, `reactive` and `isReactive`.  Use Vue 3 instead.

Here is a Vue 3 esm-browser CDN url:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@next/dist/vue.esm-browser.js
```

Comment: Big facepalm here, yeah I'm using Vue 2. Thank you so much you probably saved me hours of time :D